# BeginInvoke: Too Many Calls made

Tags: c#, delegates, begininvoke

pls look at following piece of code.

```
for (int j = 0; j < 500000; j++)  
{  
    Console.WriteLine(j);  

    // Call BeginInvoke with last two parameters as null  

    IAsyncResult asyncRes = dlg.BeginInvoke(j, 4, ref refString, out outString, progressCallBack, null);   
}
```

if the method that is being invoked asynchronously sleeps for 5 mins. then is it correct that 5 lac threads have been created?

Thanks.

Comment: dlg is object of *public delegate string TimeConsumerDelegate(int a, int b, ref string c, out string d);*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is generally not true. When you call `BeginInvoke` on a delegate, you are queuing up an asynchronous method execution.

The .NET [Threadpool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) will decide when and how to execute your method based on the queue of work items that need processing and with the aim for maximum throughput, but certainly it will not run 500000 threads in parallel.

When I tried out your example with a sleep of 5 minutes and a little console message in the delegate only 8 threads were running initially, then slowly more were trickling in.

For a good explanation on the thread pool and asynchronous delegates read [this article](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/threadpool.shtml).

Comment: I agree that 500000 lac threads won't run in parallel. my processor is Core 2 quad 4 so at max it can run 1000 threads. is that right? two more doubts: you said _provided that dlg works as expected_: wats the unexpected way? and when you say Queue. is it FIFO?

Comment: I wrote *provided dlg works as expected* before you clarified that it is a delegate, I edited my post accordingly. Up to .NET 4 work items are queued and enqueued in FIFO order, the situation is more complex with the .NET 4 thread pool since there are local queues for every worker thread in the thread pool.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It has a lot of new info for me. can you pls also tell how did you find out that how many threads are running? if i print ManagedThreadId, it's different for each call of BeignInvoke.

Comment: To see the current worker threads and their state for your application you can just pause to Debug, then select from the VS menu Debug|Windows|Threads